# Unique Find/Replace System Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, find, submit

I'm creating a really Find/Replace System but one of the main features are not working.

What's Supposed to happen:

Once you search all words found will highlight on the page. I want it so you can click it and it opens an Div saying: Replace {WORD HERE} with {INPUT} and then you can hit replace and it will replace that word with the text in the Input.

I'm using the findAndReplace Plugin and I don't want to change that.

What wont work:

Once you click on the word, the box opens, but I dont know how to make the found text replace with the one in the Input. Some of my code is in an One Line formate because I have:

```
return 'Code Here';
```

My Javascript:

```
shortcut.add("Ctrl+F", function() {
    $('#finder').animate({
        'bottom': '-53px'
    }, 100);
});
shortcut.add("Shift+F", function() {
    $('#finder').animate({
        'bottom': '0px'
    }, 100);
});
shortcut.add("Ctrl+C", function() {
    $('#finder').animate({
        'bottom': '-150px'
    }, 100);
});

function findAndReplace(searchText, replacement, searchNode) {
    if (!searchText || typeof replacement == '') {
        $('.r').css({
            'background': 'white',
            'color': 'black'
        });
        return;
    }
    if (!searchText || typeof replacement === 'undefined') {
        alert('No Items Found');
        $('.r').css({
            'background': 'white',
            'color': 'black'
        });
        return;
    }
    var regex = typeof searchText === 'string' ? new RegExp(searchText, 'g') : searchText,
        childNodes = (searchNode || document.body).childNodes,
        cnLength = childNodes.length,
        excludes = 'html,head,style,title,link,meta,script,object,iframe';
    while (cnLength--) {
        var currentNode = childNodes[cnLength];
        if (currentNode.nodeType === 1 && (excludes + ',').indexOf(currentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() + ',') === -1) {
            arguments.callee(searchText, replacement, currentNode);
        }
        if (currentNode.nodeType !== 3 || !regex.test(currentNode.data)) {
            continue;
        }
        var parent = currentNode.parentNode,
            frag = (function() {
                var html = currentNode.data.replace(regex, replacement),
                    wrap = document.createElement('div'),
                    frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
                wrap.innerHTML = html;
                while (wrap.firstChild) {
                    frag.appendChild(wrap.firstChild);
                }
                return frag;
            })();
        parent.insertBefore(frag, currentNode);
        parent.removeChild(currentNode);
    }
}
$('#find').submit(function() {

    findAndReplace(document.getElementById('fText').value, function(hi) {
        var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999999);
        var o = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999999);
        var c = 'background:white;color:black;cursor:default;';
        var id = 'changer' + n + '';
        var onclick = "$('#replace_box" + n + "').slideDown();$('#black" + n + "').show();";
        var close = "$('#replace_box" + n + "').remove();$('#black" + n + "').remove();$('#highlight" + n + "').css({'background' : 'white', 'color':'black'});";
        var click = "$('.black').hide();$('#replace_box" + n + "').slideUp(900).delay(4000).remove();$('#highlight" + n + "').html('<span id=" + id + " style=" + c + "></span>');"
        return '<div id="black' + n + '" class="black"></div><span id="highlight' + n + '" class="r" style="background: yellow;color: black;cursor:pointer;position:relative;" onclick="' + onclick + '">' + hi + '<div id="replace_box' + n + '" class="box" style="position:absolute;top:77px;left:116px;"><div style="position:relative;"><div class="close" onclick="' + close + '">Close</div>Replace <b>' + hi + '</b> with <input id="input' + n + '" autocomplete="off"/><br><br><button id="buttons' + n + '" onclick="' + click + '">Replace!</button><div class="chat-bubble-arrow"></div><div class="chat-bubble-arrow-border"></div></div></div></span>';
    });
    return false;
});
$('#replace').submit(function() {
    findAndReplace(document.getElementById('fText').value, function() {
        var mon = $('#rText').val();
        return '<span class="highlight2" style="background: white;color: black;">' + mon + '</span>';
    });
    return false;
});
```

Oh, and I'm using the Shortcut plugin to make the find Box show on CTRL+F (Replacing the Browser Find System)

Note in the Javascript this is the main code for the Find:

```
 $('#find').submit(function() {

        findAndReplace(document.getElementById('fText').value, function(hi){
        var n = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999999); 
        var o = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999999); 
        var c = 'background:white;color:black;cursor:default;';
        var id = 'changer'+n+'';
        var onclick = "$('#replace_box"+n+"').slideDown();$('#black"+n+"').show();";
        var close = "$('#replace_box"+n+"').remove();$('#black"+n+"').remove();$('#highlight"+n+"').css({'background' : 'white', 'color':'black'});";
        var click = "$('.black').hide();$('#replace_box"+n+"').slideUp(900).delay(4000).remove();$('#highlight"+n+"').html('<span id="+id+" style="+c+"></span>');"
        return '<div id="black'+n+'" class="black"></div><span id="highlight'+n+'" class="r" style="background: yellow;color: black;cursor:pointer;position:relative;" onclick="'+onclick+'">' + hi + '<div id="replace_box'+n+'" class="box" style="position:absolute;top:77px;left:116px;"><div style="position:relative;"><div class="close" onclick="'+close+'">Close</div>Replace <b>'+hi+'</b> with <input id="input'+n+'" autocomplete="off"/><br><br><button id="buttons'+n+'" onclick="'+click+'">Replace!</button><div class="chat-bubble-arrow"></div><div class="chat-bubble-arrow-border"></div></div></div></span>';
       });
       return false;
   });
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="finder">  
<div style="position:relative;">
<form id="find" style="padding-bottom:10px;">
  <button class="close2" id="wa" onclick="$('#finder').animate({'bottom' : '-150px'}, 100);">X</button>
  <input id="fText" placeholder="Enter Text you wanna replace here!" autocomplete="off" style="width:210px;"/>
  <button>Find!</button>
</form>
<form id="replace">
  <input id="rText" placeholder="Replace all of the found items." autocomplete="off" style="width:210px;"/>
  <button>Replace All</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div class="black"></div>
<div id="show"></div><div id="test"></div>
<div id="boxes"></div>
```

I also have CSS But I won't be posting that here.

My Example Is here:

[Find/Replace](http://yolatools.yolasite.com/find-replace.php)

Really hope someone can understand the way I code and can help.

Comment: I can't get your demo to work, I don't see an input and Ctrl-F opens the browser find...

Comment: OK, Fixed the Problem. Demo Works now somewhat.

Comment: Well I did a find and replace on "Press" with "Push" and it worked... what was the problem?

Comment: It's working fine for me to.  Not sure what the problem is supposed to be.

Comment: Didn't you read what I wrote. Click on one of the darn words (or letters) that you searched for. Another Box will open! The Replacing for that box doesn't work. (Single Word Replacement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your code for the "Replace" button that appears when you click on a highlighted word:

```
<button id="buttons7430059098" onclick="$('.black').hide();$('#replace_box7430059098').slideUp(900).delay(4000).remove();$('#highlight7430059098').html('&lt;span id=changer7430059098 style=background:white;color:black;cursor:default;&gt;&lt;/span&gt;');">Replace!</button>
```

What it is doing is replacing the contents of the highlighted element with an empty span.  You need to actually put whatever the user typed into the input field (`$("#input7430059098").val()`) into that span.

I would also create a function that can be called from the click handler of the button to do the replacement, as there already seems to be a lot of code right in the click handler, but that's just me.

Edit:

Try this:

`var click = "$('.black').hide();$('#replace_box"+n+"').slideUp(900).delay(4000).remove();$('#highlight"+n+"').html('<span id="+id+" style="+c+">' + $('#input" + n + "').val() + '</span>');";`

Comment: You got a point. But the Problem is I need to have this one submit function for it too work. Right now its trying to get the value of the inputs before anything is in it. In the Chrome Dev. Tool I get an Undefined.

Comment: You need to get the value of the input field when the button is clicked, not when constructing the onclick handler.  I've edited my answer - try it out and see if that works.